# What do curly braces do in a function call (as argument, NOT a parameter) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, curly-braces

So I have to work with a function call like this:

```
someFunction({ someVar });
```

My question is what do the curly braces do, why use them?

Answer (score 4):

It passes an object as the argument. The object has one property named `'someVar'` which has the value of the `someVar` variable.

```js
const someVar = 'foo';
console.log({ someVar });
```

Answer (score 0):

When you include curly braces in a function call as argument it passes an object as the argument and the key is same as the name of the variable and value as the value stored in the variable. [This is a shorthand for Object initialization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#property_definitions). See below snippet for the reference.

```js
function func(argument) {
  console.log(argument)
}

const variable = "value"
func({variable})
```

you should use this type of argument if you want to pass some value with some unique identifier as key in the function. this type of argument is widely used in reactjs for passing props in the functional components.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).